# How do I swap certain bytes in a file with python?

Tags: python, file-io, byte

I have a byte file which consists of integers that take up 4 bytes of space each. I also have function in my python code that is supposed to switch two elements in the file given their indexes.

index 0 is the first 4 byte integer, index 1 is the second batch of 4 bytes and so on.

How would I implement this in my code?

I am stuck on both - decoding and then writing back only the changes. I figured I could use fileinput to process this single long line as a string, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. Also, if I process this as a string, I'm not sure how to decode string back to bytes and then back to string properly.

EDIT: Is struct.unpack and the convenient way of opening file is a way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
def swap_in_file_array(filename, a_ind, b_ind):
    with open(filename, "r+b") as file:
        data = file.read()
        tuples = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
        a = []
        b = []
        for i in range(0, (len(tuples))):
            if i == a_ind:
                a = tuples[i]
                # print(struct.unpack("i", tupples[i])[0]) # also used for displaying things if needed
            elif i == b_ind:
                b = tuples[i]
        tuples[b_ind] = a
        tuples[a_ind] = b
        data = b''.join(tuples)
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
```

I'm sure some other code magicians could have made this code more efficient, but I'm fine with it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use mmap for something like this.  mmap.mmap() returns an bytearray object you can index.

Comment: I solved this in another way which is more "transparent" for a newbie such as me. Still, thanks!